# Interval Scheduling with with start and end times are intervals themselves

Tags: algorithm, intervals, scheduling, theory

So the classic interval scheduling problem is given a bunch of intervals [a_i, b_i] where a_i is the starting time of the interval and b_i is the ending time of the interval, find the most amount of non-overlapping intervals one can gather in a set. This problem is easy, one can use the greedy algorithm and that makes sense.

However, what if the starting time of the interval is an interval itself as well as the ending time of the interval as well. Essentially you have a list of intervals which contain intervals themselves. The motivation behind this is that often times, when one does a "task", they can start the task in an interval of time, and then can end the task in some interval of time. How would one approach/modify the interval scheduling problem to solve something of this nature.
Another way to look at this problem is that you have a bunch of "interval pairs: [a_i1, b_i1], [a_i2, b_i2]" and you want to apply the interval scheduling algorithm to these interval pairs. Same question, but perhaps a better way of looking at the problem. Can someone provide some help?

Comment: If the start and end times could be anywhere within their respective intervals, then to be safe you'd have to treat a scheduled item as if it ran from the earliest possible start to the latest possible end times... in which case you're back to a single interval effectively.

Comment: Or, alternatively, it would make sense that the *duration* is fixed, but the start time can vary.  This would be quite different from variable duration tasks.